# Python loop in the directory inside directory

Tags: python

I currently have the python code which loops in the directory, if it finds another directory inside the directory, then it goes inside it & loops it again to get all the files inside it. The directory traverse only one level. Here is the code :

```
import io
import sys, os
import glob
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

directory = u"F:\\songs"


count=0;
songs = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, u"*"))
with io.open('filenames.txt', encoding='utf-8') as newnames:
    for filename in newnames:
        try:
            print directory + "\\" + songs[count]
            if "####" in filename:
                innersongs = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, songs[count]))
                for innerfilename in innersongs:
                    print directory + "\\" + songs[count] + "\\" + innerfilename
                    os.rename(oldpath, newpath)
            else:
                print "hhy"
                os.rename(oldpath, newpath)
            count += 1
        except IOError as (errno, strerror):
            print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
        except:
            print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
            raise
```

Above is the code which does the following i mentioned. Below is the names of the file with which it gets renamed. Filename is filenames.txt

```
abcd sdfdd dfdcbv
####amcdn dfghfgn yrtyrt
@@@@abcdk eruifgf oirer
@@@@eprouri kdfjdkfd soieeure dlfkdl
@@@@weoerto oeruoture oitretre
@@@@ewpoire gkjdfkg sdfdsfl sdfsdhjfd
tieruoigd s,dfkdsjf dsfjbdjsf
dfrkewire dgngfkdgdf fdgkjdfg
gmfdghjfdhgdfg
dfgfdgdf skdfhds sdfhsdjhf sdfitertre
weikds dgkjksdf asouew sdfhds sdfj
```

Above is the sample file. In the current scenerio, whenever it gets the `####` in the file, then the script gets to know that it is the name of the directory, so go inside it & all `@@@@` are the name of the sudirectories or files in the inner directory. After `@@@@` is over, we gets out of the inner directory loop & loop over the current directory for changing the file names.

But i stuck at the inner loop to move inside & change the name of inner directory file. What wrong i am doing here ? What else i can improve in the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Such a weird format. I don't really understand what it's for, so doing a wild guess – I recommend using json, e.g. [tree.json](http://pastebin.com/RHBRRFxc).

To use this in Python:

### tree.py

```
import json

def process_tree(prefix, element):
    for key, val in zip(element.keys(), element.values()):
        if type(val) is dict:
            process_tree(key, val)
        elif type(val) is list:
            if val:
                print('Renaming {0}/{1} to {0}/{2}'.format(prefix, val[0], val[1]))

if __name__=='__main__':
    tree = json.load(open('tree.json'))
    process_tree('.', tree)
```

In this example, `json.load` converts a json into `dict` with nested `dict`s and `list`s, so you can iterate over them. Also, this example is based on recursion – process_tree calls itself to process a child `dict` while processing a parent `dict`.

Its output:

```
Renaming ./sdfdd to ./dfdcbv
Renaming ./skdfhds to ./sdfhsdjhf
Renaming amcdn/gkjdfkg to amcdn/sdfdsfl
Renaming amcdn/eruifgf to amcdn/oirer
Renaming amcdn/dfghfgn to amcdn/yrtyrt
Renaming amcdn/oeruoture to amcdn/oitretre
Renaming amcdn/kdfjdkfd to amcdn/soieeure
Renaming ./dgkjksdf to ./asouew
Renaming ./s,dfkdsjf to ./dsfjbdjsf
Renaming ./dgngfkdgdf to ./fdgkjdfg
```

Again, I don't really understand what your code was meant to do, so my code has obvious limitations. Elements with empty values (e.g. empty list) are ignored (`if val:` checks if value is empty). If element value (`val`) is not a `dict`, element name (`key`) is not used at all (otherwise, it becomes a prefix). If `list` has more than two elements, only first two are used.

Anyway, you know better how to rewrite this, if this *slightly* fits your needs. :)

Comment: Although i clearly wrote everything, but again, I already have a code which reads the directory names to 1 level deeper & stores the names in the above mentioned format with `####` & `@@@@` to keep knowing that `####` is a file not a directory, so go inside it & `@@@@` is for knowing the files are in inner directory. That script i already made it. Now i am making a script for renaming. Using some other software, i changed the names of everyfile & saved in a particular file with same order. Now i want to put the changed names to exactly the same directories. That what i am trying to achieve.